# Continuity of a bilinear form with respect to weak$^*$ topology

Tags: normed-spaces, product-space

Let $X$ be a normed linear space and let $X^*$ be its topological dual. The bilinear form
$\psi:X\times X^*\to F$ is defined by
$$\psi(x,x^*)=x^*(x).$$
Is $\psi$ continuous with respect to the topology $\tau$ on $X\times X^*$, where members of $\tau$ is of the form
$$\{U\times V:~U\text{ is open in norm topology in }X, V\text{  is open in weak${}^*$ topology in }X^*\}.$$
A detailed answer will be of very much help! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sorry, you have to do your own homework.

Comment: What do you know about the weak* topology on $X^*$?

Comment: The map is clearly continuous, with respect to the norm topology. However, what about the topology I have mentioned in the question. Is this trivial. It is not a homework problem@KaviRamaMurthy.

Comment: Weak$^*$ topology in $X^*$ is induced by the family $\Psi(X)$ on $X^*$, where $\Psi$ is the canonincal embedding of $X$ into $X^{**}$.@azif00

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your map is not continuous. The basic problem is that while a weak* convergent sequence of operators is bounded, a weak* convergent net may be unbounded.

Work over real Banach spaces for simplicity. Consider $\phi^{-1}(-1, 1).$ This set is not open in the topology you describe, which we prove as follows.

Assume that it was open. Note that this set definitely includes the pair $(0, 0)$. So, it should contain some open set $U\times V$ where $U$ is a norm open set containing the 0 vector, and $V$ is a weak* open set containing the 0 functional.

The problem: any weak* open set $V$ containing the 0 functional has to contain a line, i.e. a one-dimensional space of functionals. (In fact, it contains many such lines. The idea is to look at the basic open sets of the weak* topology.)

Take some $f\neq 0$ so that the line generated by $f$ is contained in $V.$ Then pick $u \in U$ so that $u \not\in\ker f.$ This is possible since in the norm topology, an open ball at 0 contains vectors in every direction.

We must have that $\lambda f(u) \in (-1, 1)$ for every possible $\lambda,$ since $\lambda f \in V$ and $u\in U$ for every choice of $\lambda.$ But by scaling, since $f(u)\neq 0,$ this is clearly impossible!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, I do not understand the problem paragraph. Also, what do you mean by $\phi^{-1}(1,1)$? The range of the bilinear form is clearly a scalar field.

Comment: @pmun Yes, so I mean pullback the open interval $(-1, 1),$ sorry if that was not clear.

Comment: @pmun The problem is that if $V$ is a weak* open set containing 0, then it contains a 1-dimensional subspace of $X^*.$ Try proving that every basic weak* open set has to have this property, and then you're golden.

Comment: I understood@michael